# Why does my javascript window.open function read the urls, but not the width and height parameters from an array?

Tags: javascript

Years ago, I built my website with a lot of flash functionality, though based on html files. I've been working on html/css/javascript alternatives, but got stuck on one last page. It includes a simple (javascript) slide show with backwards and forwards buttons and a clickable image that opens into a customized window. In the Flash version the images are swf files with the following actionscript embedded:

```
movieclip_inst.onRelease = function():Void {    
getURL("javascript:openNewWindow('Photopages/A01La_Jolla1.html', 925, 693)");
}
```

calling the following javascript function in the head of the html file:

```
    function openNewWindow(page, width, height) { 
OpenWin = this.open(page, "Illustrationslideshow", "toolbar=no, menubar=no ,location=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, statusbar=no, width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", top=" + (screen.height/2 - height/2) + ", left=" + (screen.width/2 - width/2) + "\""); 
}
```

This opens up the individual html files, that are listed in an external array, like so:

```
function setupPages() {
var pages = new Array();

pages[0] = 'Photopages/A01La_Jolla1.html', 925, 690;
pages[1] = 'Photopages/A02La_Jolla2.html', 888, 650;
. . .
return pages;
}
```

This works perfectly with the Flash version, but when I try to apply the function in the body of the html file:

```
<a href="javascript:void()#" onclick="openNewWindow(pages[currentSlideNum])"><img src="images/photosforswfs/La_Jolla_01.jpg" id="artwork" /></a>
```

it will only call up the html image file, but not adhere to the sizes I set. The windows open up in the same size as the originating window or as a tiny square, depending on the browser. Here's the set up of the pages variable in the head of the html document:

```
var pages = new Array();
pages = setupPages();
```

The array also contains the images and captions, set up in the same way:

```
function setupSlides() {
var slides = new Array();

slides[0] = 'images/photosforswfs/La_Jolla_01.jpg'; 
...
return slides;
}
```

and

```
function setupCaptions() {
var captions = new Array();

captions[0] = '<br />Louis Karhn building in La Jolla, CA | 1';
...
return captions;
}
```

The slide show is set up as follows:

```
var slides = new Array();
slides = setupSlides();

var captions = new Array();
captions = setupCaptions();

var currentSlideNum = 0;
var numSlides = slides.length;

function previousSlide() {
   if (currentSlideNum == 0) {
   currentSlideNum = numSlides-1;
   } else {
   currentSlideNum--;
   }
   var slideObj = document.getElementById('artwork');
   slideObj.src = slides[currentSlideNum];
   var captionObj = document.getElementById('caption');
   captionObj.innerHTML = captions[currentSlideNum];
}

function nextSlide() {
if (currentSlideNum == numSlides-1) {
   currentSlideNum = 0;
   } else {
   currentSlideNum++;
   }
   var slideObj = document.getElementById('artwork');
   slideObj.src = slides[currentSlideNum];
   var captionObj = document.getElementById('caption');
   captionObj.innerHTML = captions[currentSlideNum];
    }
```

What I am doing wrong? I am a total newbie, cutting and pasting code rather than writing it. Nothing I tried would fix the problem. Please help!
janeDee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pages[0] array position is saving only Photopages/A01La_Jolla1.html and returning the last value (690).
If you want to have all that data in the pages array, you could make it an object or another array:

```
pages[0] = ['Photopages/A01La_Jolla1.html', 925, 690];
```

this way you would have ask for `pages[0][1]` and `pages[0][2]` to get the sizes.

other way is using an object:

```
pages[0] = {url:'Photopages/A01La_Jolla1.html', w:925, h:690};
```

This way you would have to ask for: `pages[0].w` and `pages[0].h`

At the end, of course, you'd need to change a bit the call to your function to specify that with is pages[0].w and so on, but that is simple.

```
openNewWindow(pages[0].url, pages[0].w, pages[0].h);
```

or you could just send the array item and let the function extract the info from the inside:

```
function openNewWindow(page) { 
    var OpenWin = window.open(page.url, "Illustrationslideshow", "toolbar=no, menubar=no ,location=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, statusbar=no, width=" + page.w+ ", height=" + page.h+ ", top=" + (screen.height/2 - height/2) + ", left=" + (screen.width/2 - width/2) + "\""); 
}
openNewWindow(pages[0]);
```

Comment: First of all: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me for the longest time...

Comment: Sorry... I think I should've explained a bit more. I have 22 images and page in the array and they all show up. The simple slide show is defining the [currentSlideNum] through the variable var slideObj:
       var slideObj = document.getElementById('artwork');
       slideObj.src = slides[currentSlideNum];

Comment: could you edit your question adding all this details so that I can understand it better? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry... I think I should've explained a bit more. I have 22 images and html pages in the array and they all show up. The simple slide show is defining the [currentSlideNum] through the variable `var slideObj`:
       `var slideObj = document.getElementById('artwork');`
       `slideObj.src = slides[currentSlideNum];`
The link `<a href=...>`contains the `id="artwork"`. This way the correct html page shows up with the image (and caption).

Comment: maybe you can give me a pen in codepen or some other web?

Comment: too much of a newbie to know what that is, or being able to provide that. Would it help, if I uploaded the test page, so you can see it in action? 
I mean: upload onto my site.

Comment: I forked a new version of your pen so that you can see some changes, but I think that the answer was already fine. Just for organization purposes, if you have more problems that do not relate to that array construction, I think you should make another question with a different subject.

Comment: OMG, I finally got it to work! Thank you so much. Never did see the changes in your fork, though...

Answer (score 1):

I used the object variant that was described. In the external js file I changed the existing pages array to the following:

```
function setupPages() {
var pages = new Array();

pages[0] = {url:'Photopages/A01La_Jolla1.html', w:925, h:690};
pages[1] = {url:'Photopages/A02La_Jolla2.html',  w:688, h:918};
...
return pages;
```

}

and call the function in the link tag like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void()#" onclick="openNewWindow(pages[currentSlideNum].url, pages[currentSlideNum].w, pages[currentSlideNum].h);">
```